# Diferença em usar a cláusula using dentro do namespace

Tags: c#, .net

Existe alguma diferença em desempenho / execução / compilação de código C# ao se utilizar as cláusulas `using` dentro do namespace?

Basicamente o que quero saber é se há diferença (além da estruturação) nos seguintes trechos de código:

```
namespace Projeto.App
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using Projeto.App.Views;
    ...
```

e

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Projeto.App.Views;

namespace Projeto.App
{
    ...
```